# Ubuntu 22.04 won't wake after screen lock / screen dim

Tags: gnome, screen, freeze, gdm, lock

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 and it won't wake after screen lock. This is true for both, X11 and Wayland (also disabling Wayland for gdm3 doesn't help). System suspend works fine, only screen-lock or screen dim cause the system to freeze.
How can I investigate the issue?

`journalctrl` doesn't show anything extraordinary.

```
$ journalctl -b -1 -e
May 09 15:50:01 pavilion systemd[5279]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 09 15:50:01 pavilion systemd[5279]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 09 15:50:04 pavilion ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[9054]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
May 09 15:50:04 pavilion ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[9054]: unable to update icon for livepatch
May 09 15:50:06 pavilion geoclue[1483]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
May 09 15:50:06 pavilion systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

I'm using integrated GPU (Intel i5-8250U).

**EDIT**
Funny enough, the system hangs even when it's freshly restarted and stays couple of minutes on GDM3 login screen (without login into Gnome). So it's definitely an issue with GDM3!
Anyway, I have neither time, nor patience to resolve it. I've downgraded back to Ubuntu 20.04.

**EDIT#2**
Even more funnily, now Ubuntu 20.04 also hangs. I guess this is related to Gnome (v3.36.8) or GDM3.

Comment: Do the keys Ctrl+Alt+F3, F4, etc. work after screen lock? I have a similar problem, but only in Wayland.

Comment: Nope, the system looks completely frozen after the screen is turned off after screenlock.

Comment: +1 for this Having the exact same problem.

Comment: heh, after updading Ubuntu 20.04 I'm having the same issues as with fresh installation of 22.04. so now, the problem seems to be present in both 22.04 and 20.04 with the latest udpates installed.

Comment: +1 from me. Locked wayland means hard reboot of my laptop. I'm back on X11 until someone figures this out.

Comment: for me switching GDM3 to X11 solved the problem, but the laptop hangs from time to time upon screen dim. but at least it's not very common problem anymore.

Comment: +1; I have the exact same problem

Comment: meanwhile, I've switched to Debian 11. no problems for several weeks :) I guess I'll start migrating other computers to Debian in coming months...

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here...

You can try to debug (what I assume is) `xdg-screensaver`. Set the environment variable `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` on an invocation of the screensaver ([source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/xdg-utils/+/refs/heads/main/scripts/xdg-screensaver)). Something like this:

`XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-screensaver activate 2&> $HOME/lockscreen.debug`

It may help guide your troubleshooting to see what is in the log output. If that doesn't work, you could always try to put some `logger` messages into the `xdg-screensaver` script to see where it may be getting to and/or breaking when trying to return.

Something like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835943/how-to-determine-function-name-from-inside-a-function), but write it to a file so you can troubleshoot the script execution and where it may be failing.

**Edit**: You can do something similar with `xfce4-screensaver`:

`xfce4-screensaver --no-daemon --debug 2&> $HOME/lockscreen.debug`